# Image transition jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, transition

I'm attempting to use jQuery to mimic an image slideshow on my main page for potential customers.  I just want the images to smoothly transition.  image0.jpg ... imagen.jpg.  Please note the single quotes within the javascript are because the mark-up is enclosed within  tags.

JAVASCRIPT:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function swapImages()
            {
                  var $active = $(\'#myGallery .active\');
                  var $next = ($(\'#myGallery .active\').next().length > 0) ? $(\'#myGallery .active\').next() : $(\'#myGallery img:first\');
                  $active.fadeOut(function(){
                  $active.removeClass(\'active\');
                  $next.fadeIn().addClass(\'active\');
                  });
            }

            $(document).ready(function(){
                // Run our swapImages() function every 5secs
                setInterval(\'swapImages()\', 5000);
            }

        </script>
```

CSS:

```
        <style type="text/css">
        .clear
        {
            clear:left;
        }

        /* transition effects */
        #myGallery
        {
            position:relative;
            width:1000px; /* Set your image width */
            height:400px; /* Set your image height */
        }
        #myGallery img
        {
            display:none;
            position:absolute;
            top:0;
            left:0;
        }
        #myGallery img.active
        {
            display:block;
        }
        </style>
```

HTML:

```
                <div id="myGallery">
                    <img src="'.$baseLink.'/images/slide/0.jpg" alt="Wholesalers" class="active" />
                    <img src="'.$baseLink.'/images/slide/1.jpg" alt="Premier eShop Software" />
                    <img src="'.$baseLink.'/images/slide/2.jpg" alt="Team Work" />
                </div>
```

Comment: So, what is your problem?

Comment: So what happens when you run that code? Errors in the browser console?

Comment: $(\'#myGallery .active\').next().length Don't you mean .index() instead of .length ?

Comment: `}` should be `});` for closing the `ready`.

Comment: No transition takes place, just /images/slide/0.jpg is visible, no transition to 1.jpg...

Comment: Marcel, you are absolutely right.